# Running classification inference on EDge TPU USB without reloading model every time

Tags: python, image, classification, tpu

I am quite new to Tensor Flow / Edge TPU usage.
While I mange to run an image classification with the classify_image.py script 
it has a very poor performance on the Edge TPU USB module because it always loads the model and kind of reboots the device (you see the Win10 device manager reinstalling it at every run of the script).
Is there any way to run a python script that classifies an image with the last loaded model in the USB dongle, avoiding the 3-5 seconds of device configuration time ?

Comment: Could you please update the question with some more details on what the task is, what your setup/process is, what the expected results are, what your results are. This will allow people to understand the problem and give you useful advice, as opposed to random information that might not be helpful at all for your usecase.
What is classify_image.py? I suppose a bit of knowledge on the topic is required but still wouldn't hurt to point to resources that you are using such as source code, documentation, etc.

Comment: I followed the sample quide from Coral: [link]https://coral.ai/docs/accelerator/get-started/    but with my own tensor flow compiled model. As I said, this works as expected but I would need to rerun the script with different pictures without reloading the model every time causing the 5 second device config delay.

Comment: What I would like to do is:

python classify_image.py --model Mymodel.tflite --labels Mylabels.txt --input 1stpicture.bmp   (takes 5 seconds, no problem)

python reclassify --input 2ndpicture.bmp    (should not take more than a few ms)


So I am looking for a "reclassify" script here.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you should load the model first and store it. Then when you use it for invoking, you just need to allocate tensor, then pass to it the input. You can keep your script in while loop waiting for your input (ie sending through websocket,... or loading a directory). But according to what I see, you will have to self load the image to the model,so there is really hard to self-allocate a fixed part of TPU to your model.